# How to move a semi class into its own file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Right now I have the below in one file, and would like to move the `Clock` function/class into its own file.

I don't know what to call it, as I suppose it is a function, but with some class features.

If I change

```
var Clock = function(options) {
```

to

```
module.exports = (options) => {
```

and then

```
var Clock = require('./functions/clock')
var timer = new Clock({delay: options.checkInterval});
```

then I get

```
TypeError: Clock is not a constructor
```

## Question

Does anyone know how to move this function into its own file, so I have `index.js` and `functions/clock.js`?

```
var Clock = function(options) {
  var timer, offset, clock, interval

  options = options || {}
  options.delay = options.delay || 1000

  reset()

  function start() {
    if (!interval) {
      offset = Date.now()
      interval = setInterval(update, options.delay)
    }
  }

  function update() {
    clock += delta()
  }

  function delta() {
    var now = Date.now(),
    d = now - offset;
    offset = now;
    return d;
  }

  function stop() {
    if (interval) {
      clearInterval(interval)
      interval = null
    }
  }

  function reset() {
    clock = 0
  }

  function read() {
    return clock
  }

  this.start = start
  this.stop  = stop
  this.reset = reset
  this.read  = read
}

// all the following should not be moved
...
var timer = new Clock({delay: options.checkInterval});
...
```

Comment: just do `module.exports Clock`

Comment: If I do that then NodeJS complains about `Clock` with `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

Comment: sorry forgot the `=` in it `module.exports = Clock`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing your export, it seems like you are exporting an `arrow function` and unfortunately, we can't use the arrow functions for `constructor` call (i.e we can't use `new` with them ) because they do not have the `[[Construct]]` method. As such, the `prototype` property also does not exist for arrow functions.

So just change your arrow function to normal function and you would be good to go.

```
var Clock = function(options) {
  var timer, offset, clock, interval

  options = options || {}
  options.delay = options.delay || 1000

  reset()

  function start() {
    if (!interval) {
      offset = Date.now()
      interval = setInterval(update, options.delay)
    }
  }

  function update() {
    clock += delta()
  }

  function delta() {
    var now = Date.now(),
    d = now - offset;
    offset = now;
    return d;
  }

  function stop() {
    if (interval) {
      clearInterval(interval)
      interval = null
    }
  }

  function reset() {
    clock = 0
  }

  function read() {
    return clock
  }

  this.start = start
  this.stop  = stop
  this.reset = reset
  this.read  = read
}
  module.exports = Clock;
```